# How to use jquery and jqueryui for Internet Explorer add-on creation?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, browser-addons

As a hobby thing, I am trying to create Internet Explorer Add-on using this article [Creating Add-ons for Internet Explorer: Customizing Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

The above links describes two approaches:

1. Using javascript
2. Using DLL

I am trying to use Javascript for my project. Specifically, jqueryui for all the ui rendering. The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to include/use jqueryui in my add-on.

**ADD**

With jqueryui i am mostly interested in the dialog boxes and modal forms, activated from the context menu. Is it possible to do this?

Any direction, suggestion or code snippet is welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do any graphical stuff with the menus unless you go the DLL route - in which case you won't be using JavaScript. It looks like all you can do from JS is add menu items (as plain text).

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by **graphical stuff**. With jqueryui i am mostly interested in the dialog boxes and modal forms, activated from the context menu. Is it possible? As for the DLL thingy, I have already explored and able to use it. Right now just looking at the javascript approach. Thanks.